# Amazon Product Advertising API returns price zero

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

[image]

I am using Amazon Product Advertising API to get product data, and using ASIN number to lookup.

If i use ASIN number of product which do not have any dropdown or criteria for price, API returns price successfully. for example, below data returns price successfully.

```
ASIN: B01E53XDKG
```

But product with dropdown does not returns price. Please look the image.

Comment: Using https://packagist.org/packages/marcl/amazonproductapi

Comment: having the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: kamel-labiad , Yes i found a solution.

Comment: I found it too never mind